# How to authenticate in Windows 8.1 App?

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-8

I'm fairly new to developing an Windows 8.1 app and I'm trying to find a way to allow the user to authenticate through our own custom authentication via a php web service. I've only found how to do this through online providers (i.e. - Facebook, Google, Live, etc) but these won't work for our case. Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I can can set this up?

Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: So you are surprised that you cannot find documentatiom about your own custom authentication system, and now you want to ask here if someone might have it after all?

Answer (score 1):

To save User credential for a windows store app is to use the [PasswordVault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault) which will save your credential in an encripted files. You can find an complete sample on how to use it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a PHP web service you can create a REST API script.
This script would accept the username and password as query string and would returned if the user is authenticated or not not through a JSON response after having compared it with your database. 
 
For example
www.w8developer.com/login?username=w8developer&password=password  
 these two paramters will be taken as input to your php script which will compare with your database and then return status as OK or unauthorized etc.